# How to display the browser's cursor image in a div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cursor, mouse

Is it possible to display the cursor images on something else than the cursor?

For example as the background of a div:

```
div{
   background:pointer;
}
```

If yes, how do you do this?

Comment: If you would like a "cursor" to appear as a background, you will need to use an image (local or online) and reference it in your css like this: `background-image: url('myImage.jpg');`See cursor image: [Cursor Image](https://www.pinpng.com/pngs/m/298-2986876_mouse-pointer-arrow-ps-computer-png-image-windows.png)

Comment: what are you looking to accomplish? if there is no cursor image on the cursor, how do you know where your cursor is. you could use @Moïze solution below, replace the image with a blank or translucent image, then use a cursor image on your background

Comment: @sao I think he just wants to get the current cursor as an image that he can display in the background of a DIV.

Comment: Barmar, you're right. @sao there would be a normal cursor, but I want to display its image as background. Since there must be the images for the cursor somwhere in the browser, how can I get access to them?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible and it's simple like this:

```css
.yourClass {
  cursor:url('https://i.ibb.co/W0HGGPB/css.png'), auto;   
}
```

```html
<button class='yourClass'>Move your mouse over</button>
```

Also note that the ideal cursor image size is: 36x36

Comment: I think he wants something that gets the current cursor image dynamically.

Comment: I don't think he wants to change the cursor, he wants to get the cursor icon and use it as an image.

Comment: Maybe you're right @Barmar, but let's wait to see if he reacts to this answer.

Comment: @Barmar, you're right. I don't want to change the current cursor, but use its image also for a background.